# 2 different ul inside div block and show same lineage column css not effect overflow

Tags: html, css, html-lists, overflow

I want to list 2 different ul like a table and each list element like a     column lineage. ı did it but when I school on x line some ul  CSS does not effect (hover background color).

Second UL 4 and first UL 4  not effect background color.

```css
ul {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: red;
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

li {
  width: 33%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dataBlock {
  overflow-x: auto;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div clas="dataBlock">


  <ul>
    <li> first UL 1
      <li> first UL 2
        <li> first UL 3
          <li> first UL 4
            <li> first UL 5
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li> second UL 1
      <li>second UL 2
        <li>second UL 3
          <li>second UL 4
            <li> second UL 5
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are missing `</li>` at the end of each `li` and you can achieve the desired effect using flexbox

```css
.dataBlock {
  overflow-x: auto;
}

ul {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  min-width: 200%;
  list-style: none
}

li {
  flex: 0 33%;
}
```

```html
<div clas="dataBlock">
  <ul>
    <li> first UL 1</li>
    <li> first UL 2 </li>
    <li> first UL 3 </li>
    <li> first UL 4 </li>
    <li> first UL 5</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li> second UL 1</li>
    <li>second UL 2</li>
    <li>second UL 3</li>
    <li>second UL 4 </li>
    <li> second UL 5</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```